# How to make negative of a variable? C++

Tags: c++, variables, negative-integer

I apologize if this error is the result of a typo, but I can't figure out how to make my variable negative when the correct syntax should be y=-x;

```
std::cout << "loop size = " << loop_size_ << std::endl;
core::Size neg_loop_size_ = -loop_size_;
std::cout << "neg loop size = " << neg_loop_size_ << std::endl;
```

When I run it, this is the result I get:

```
loop size = 4
neg loop size = 18446744073709551612
```

How do I get a new variable equal to -4?

Comment: It's an unsigned integral type that's why you are not getting negative value. The data type of core::Size should be signed to hold native integer

Comment: It seems that `core::Size` is an *unsigned* integer type, which means it can never be "negative". What happens if you attempt to *print* `-loop_size_`?

Comment: That makes sense that it's unsigned - core::Size is an integer, intended for something that never goes negative. I will use a different data type... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undoubtedly a signedness issue.  You have specified that neg_loop_size is `core::Size`.  `core::Size` is likely meant to be a length-style measurement.  A length cannot be negative.  ("How many kilometers did you run today, Josy?", "Why, I ran negative 4 kilometers!")

So, the compiler and `cout` are correctly coercing -1 to "loop around" to the highest number possible with 8 bytes.  Consider:

```
   18446744073709551612 + 4 - 1
 = 2^65 -1
 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
 = (core::Size) 0 - 1
```

If you want a negative value, you will either need to do some string manipulation and conversion yourself, or choose a datatype that the compiler and `cout` will interpret as negative.  For example:

```
int i = 0;
i -= 1;
std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: Yes, core::Size is exactly that, a length measurement. Using int fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is Core:Size data type is unsigned. So you are having issue.

If you store the value in a integer you should get the required output.

```
  int main() {
      int i = 5;
      int j = -i;
      cout<<endl<< j << endl;

     return 1;
}
```

Output ---

```
$>:~/tmp$ vim c.cpp
$>:~/tmp$ g++ c.cpp
$>:~/tmp$ ./a.out
-5
$
```